# which is faster: in-memory decompression or accessing uncompressed data in HDD

Tags: performance, io, compression, in-memory

I have a dataset larger than main memory. After compression, it fits into memory. However, in-memory decompression is kind of compute-intensive. 
Compared to accessing uncompressed data in hard drive, does in-memory decompression have any advantage in term of time-to-completion? assuming data from HDD will loaded into memory in its entirety (i.e. no random access to HDD during processing). Anyone has done any benchmark before. Thanks.

Comment: It depends. What kind of compression? For example, LZO would be very fast, while bzip would actually be fairly compute-intensive.

Answer (score 5):

First, the data has to be compressible.  If there is no compression, then obviously compressing to the HDD and decompressing back will be slower.  Many files on a HDD are not compressible because they are already compressed, e.g. image files, video files, audio files, and losslessly compressed archives like zip or .tar.gz files.

If it is compressible, [zlib](http://zlib.net/) decompression is likely to be faster than HDD reads, and [lz4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/) decompression is very likely to be faster.

This is the classic sort of question which can only be correctly answered with "it depends" followed by "you need to measure it for your situation".

Answer (score 4):

If you can decompress at least as fast as the HDD reads the data, and you decompress in parallel with the disk read, then reading of compressed data will almost always be faster (read of smaller file will finish sooner and decompression adds only latency of the last block).

According to [this benchmark](http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks.html) a [pretty weak CPU](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Athlon+XP+2400%2B) can decompress gzip at over 60MB/s.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your data, on how you're processing it, and the specs of your machine.  A few considerations that make this almost impossible to answer without profiling your exact scenario:

- how good is your compression?  Different compression algorithms use differing amounts of CPU.
- how is the data used?  The amount of data that you need to buffer before processing will affect how much you can multi-thread between decompression and processing, which will massively affect your answer.
- what's your environment?  A 16-core server with 1TB of data to process is very different to a fancy phone with 1GB of data, but it's not clear from your question which you're dealing with (HDD suggests a computer rather than a phone at least, but server vs desktop is still relevant).
- how much random access are you doing once the data is loaded?  You suggest there'll be no random access to the HDD after loading, but if you're loading the full compressed data and only decompressing a portion of data at a time, the pattern of access to the data is important - you might have decompress everything twice (or more!) to process.

Ultimately this question is hugely subjective and, if you think the performance difference will be important, I'd suggest you create some basic test scenarios and profile heavily.

As a more specific example: if you're doing heavy-duty audio or visual processing, the process is CPU intensive but will typically accept a stream of data.  In that scenario, compression would probably slow you down as the bottleneck will be the CPU.

Alternatively, if you're reading a billion lines of text from a file and counting the total number of vowels in each, your disk IO will probably be the bottleneck, and you would benefit from reducing the disk IO and working the CPU harder by decompressing the file.

Answer (score 2):

In our case, we optimized our batch processing code that would go through structured messages (read: tweets) in batch processing mode; switching the representation from JSON to [msgpack](/questions/tagged/msgpack), and mapping the entire files using `mmap`, we got into a state where it was clearly I/O-bound with speed of the magnetic disk being the limiting factor.

We found out that the `msgpack`ed messages containing mostly UTF-8 text could be compressed with compression ratios of 3-4 with [LZ4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4); after switching to LZ4 decompression our optimized code was still I/O-bound, but the throughput increased significantly.

In your case, I'd start experimenting with LZ4.